# Return ALL entries of a pandas DataFrame that have the maximal value for one of the axes?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this is such a basic question but I can't seem to find any solutions for this EXACT problem...

I have a DataFrame such as the one below and I need to find the Entries for maxmimum value of "B". In the case below I expect Entries 2 and 3 with B = 25. Any solution that either returns the index of the entry or the entire entry will do.

```
Name: 6417, dtype: float64
          A     B     C
0      8.00     0     0
1     24.00    20     5
2     31.20    25    10
3     30.00    25    15
4      3.20    20    20
```

note: I've seen some posts talking about using pd.idxmax() but this only returns the index of ONE entry even if there are multiple entries for a maximal value of a given axis.

Cheers

Comment: you can just compare with max and return  using boolean indexing: `output = df[df['B'].eq(df['B'].max())]`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way :

```py
def function(dataframe):

    list_max, max = [], 0

    for row in dataframe.itertuples():

        if row.B > max:        
            max = row.B
            list_max.clear()
            list_max.append(row.Index)

        elif row.B = max:
            list_max.append(row.Index)

    return list_max, max
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

As @anky_91 said, use the [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#boolean-indexing) to get the values you want.

```py
data={
    "A": [8.00,24.00,31.20,30.00,3.20], 
    "B": [0,20,25,25,20], 
    "C": [0,5,10,15,20] 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
max_b = df[df['B'] == df['B'].max()]
max_b.head()
```

Outputs:

```py
    A   B   C
2   31.2    25  10
3   30.0    25  15
```

Basically, `df['B'] == df['B'].max()` returns this:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

The `df` uses this to filter out the rows and keeps only the True rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
#input data
d = {'A': [8,7,7,2,3], 'B': [0,20,25,25,20], 'C': [8,7,7,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#sorting by values in column B
df = df.sort_values(by=['B'], ascending=False)

#finding the max value in column B
maxValue = df['B'].max()

#finding rows which have max value in column B
n = df.loc[df['B'] == maxValue]

#printing the result
print(n)
```

output:

```
   A   B  C
2  7  25  7
3  2  25  2
```

Comment: second step (#sorting by values in column B) is actually not needed, sorry for that